How can i fix validation check on scvmm?
I made a Hyper-V Cluster using two servers, passed the cluster validation check, and added the cluster on SCVMM successfully.
But when I tried the validation check on SCVMM, the result failed with the error below:

Validate resource health
Description: Verify that cluster resources are online and list cluster resources running in other resource monitors.

Started: 9/25/2024 9:25:58 AM.

Validating the cluster resource Virtual Machine Cluster WMI.

The cluster resource store QoS resource is being validated.

Validating cluster resource IP address: 10.10.10.10.

Cluster Resource Cluster Disk 1 is being validated.

Cluster resource Cluster Disk 2 is being validated.

CLUSTER RESOURCE NAME: VALIDATING "XXXX-CLUSTER".

Network Name Resource Name: "XXXX-CLUSTER" is checking for Active Directory issues.

"""An error occurred while running the test.
The operation failed. An error occurred while resolving the Active Directory organizational unit for the cluster name resource.

The parameter is wrong"""

Stopped: 9/25/2024 9:27:23 AM.


SCVMM service account has the following permissions:

Account Operators
Administrators
Domain Admins
Domain Users
Enterprise Admins

